# If $\int_0^1 f(x)x^{2n+1}dx=0$ for all but finitely many $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then $f=0$ on $[0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, weierstrass-approximation

Let $f$ be continuous real function. Assume $\int_0^1 f(x)x^{2n+1}dx=0$ for all but finitely many $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then $f=0$ on $[0,1]$.

Use Stone-Weierstrass theorem (not change of variables.)

*If we loosen up the problem: say $\int_0^1 f(x)x^ndt=0$ for all but finitely many $n$, without changing the variable how would stone weierstrass work here?

*What about $x^2n$ for all $n\geq 0$, infinity many terms are 0 and infinity many terms may not be 0?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g(x) = xf(x).$ Then $\int_0^1g(x)x^{2n}\, dx=0$ for $n\ge $ some $N.$ In particular

$$\tag 1 \int_0^1g(x)(x^{2N})^m\, dx=0,\,\, m=1,2,\dots.$$

Now by Stone-Weierstrass, polynomials in $x^{2N}$ are dense in $C[0,1].$ Hence there is a sequence of polynomials $p_k$ such that $p_k(x^{2N}) \to g(x)$ uniformly on $[0,1].$ But note $g(0)=0.$ It follows that $p_k(x^{2N})-p_n(0) \to g(x)$ uniformly on $[0,1].$ Since each $p_k(x^{2N})-p_n(0)$ is a finite linear combination of the monomials $(x^{2N})^m,\, m=1,2,\dots,$ we have by $(1)$

$$\int_0^1 g(x)[p_k(x^{2N})-p_n(0)]\,dx = 0$$

for all $k.$ Therefore $\int_0^1 g(x)^2\,dx =0,$ which implies $g\equiv 0,$ hence $f\equiv 0.$

Comment: Can this method be generalized to show the following: if there is a strictly increasing sequence $a_k:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ such that $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)x^{n} dx = 0$ whenever $n=a_i$ for some $i$, then $f \equiv 0$?

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122   Good question. The answer is certainly no. Look up the Muntz-Szasz theorem in all its glory, a most beautiful theorem indeed. I wonder if there is an easy answer to your question.

Answer (score 2):

[Müntz–Szász theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%BCntz%E2%80%93Sz%C3%A1sz_theorem) provides an interesting overkill. The series $\sum_{d\geq 0}\frac{1}{2d+1}$ is clearly divergent and it stays so if we remove from it a finite number of terms. It follows that the span of $x^{2d+1}$ is dense in $C^0=[0,1]$, which is dense in $L^2(0,1)$. So if the original identity holds, $f$ has to be $0$ almost everywhere on $(0,1)$. Since $f$ is a continuous function, $f\equiv 0$.

---

As an alternative, let us consider the polynomials of the form 
$$P_{a,b}(x)=C_{a,b}\, x^{2a+1}(1-x^2)^b$$ 
with $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$, 
with $C_{a,b}$ chosen in such a way that $\int_{0}^{1}P_{a,b}(x)\,dx=1$.
We may chose $a$ and $b$ in such a way that $P_{a,b}(x)\geq 0$ is concentrated in a arbitrarily small neighbourhood of any $x_0\in(0,1)$, since $P_{a,b}$ attains its maximum at $\sqrt{\frac{2a+1}{2a+2b+1}}$.
 Assume that $f\neq 0$ in a neighbourhood of $x_0\approx\sqrt{\frac{2a+1}{2a+2b+1}}$. Then
$$ \int_{0}^{1}P_{a,b}(x)\,f(x)\,dx $$
is arbitrarily close to both $f(x_0)\neq 0$ and $0$, contradiction.

Comment: This is a little hard for me to digest... Can we simply use Stone weierstrass theorem with some not specified set of polynomials? Thank you

Comment: What if $N=k+1?$

Comment: my idea: (probably false) Since $f$ is continuous on a closed set, we have a set of polynomials approaching $f$ uniformly. Let this set of polynomials be in $t^\lambda$. It would be nice if the polynomials are $0$ through out all the terms. But I have problem with this"all but finitely many..."

Comment: Life is hard. In order to tackle the problem through Stone-Weierstrass, you have to show that your algebra separates points. How do you plan to do it without invoking polynomials?

Comment: Do I really need to show what kind of polynomials are in the set? Seems like you listed a specific kind of polynomials.

Comment: By Weierstrass approximation Theorem, there is a sequence of polynomials uniformly approximating $f$ on $[0,1]$, but you need **odd** polynomials and a finite number of monomials is not allowed.

Comment: @zhw.: what is the issue if $N=k+1$? I cannot see.

Comment: @2ndaccount: I used Bernstein polynomials, the same polynomials usually exploited in a classical proof of the Weierstrass approximation Theorem.

Comment: true. Assume there is a set of some sort of odd polynomials approaching $f$ uniformly. Is it still finitely many monomials not allowed?

Comment: Assume for all $n\geq 0$. $2n+1$ is odd. so all the odd terms are 0. What about even? So I wonder if I have separate out the term $n$ in the power, then write a polynomial in $x^{something}$... but I'm having problem with that.

Comment: @2ndaccount: by your hypothesis, in a finite number of cases, even if $d$ is odd, you cannot say anything on $\int_{0}^{1}f(x) x^d\,dx$.

Comment: Then you're integrating against $x^k- x^{k+1}.$ But $x^{k+1}$ is even.

Comment: @zhw.: oh, my bad. You are right, I am going to fix this issue.

Comment: I know that. But if the power is just $n$, then certainly things are a lot easier. All polynomials will be 0. If we loosen up a little, say instead of that power "2n+1", but just $n$ for all $n$ but finitely many, how would deal with the finely many $n$ that is not guaranteed to be 0? without changing the variable, but only stone weierstrass? Thank you.

Comment: @2ndaccount: I already answered such question. You may construct an algebra that separates points by considering odd polynomials whose monomial with the smallest degree has an exponent $\geq M$, and that is all you need.